# Why is relative positioning only working after page refresh? (floating action button on material UI AppBar)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-position

I am having a lot of trouble debugging this issue as it only occurs immediately after I run 'npm run start', after performing a single page refresh everything shows up in the correct position as if there were no issues at all...

There are three floating buttons on my application's top bar which I have set relative positions so that they are shifted down slightly to overlap the work area.

They show up in the perfect place after a page refresh has been performed. And the positioning changes (left or right) relative to a drawer which may or may not be open and on screen.

Does anyone know what might cause this issue on the first page load only?

I have tried absolute positioning, which sets all the floating buttons uttermost left of the page on first load, but then in the correct positions after refresh.

I'm keen to know what would cause the page to render these buttons in strange positions on the first load if anyone has any ideas I am all ears.

Thanks

**Floating action buttons with styles**

```
import { makeStyles, styled } from '@mui/styles';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Add, ChevronLeft, Remove } from '@mui/icons-material';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Fab from '@mui/material/Fab';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';

const drawerWidth = 440;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
    return{
        bar: {
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row-reverse",
            backgroundColor: deepPurple[500],
        },
        drawer: {
            width: drawerWidth
        },
        origAppbar: theme.mixins.drawer,
        zoomFab: {
            position: 'relative',
            zIndex: 1,
            top: 80,
            left: (drawerOpen) => {return drawerOpen ? 0 : 430},
            right: 10,
        },
        zoomOutFab: {
            position: 'relative',
            zIndex: 1,
            top: 80,
            left: (drawerOpen) => {return drawerOpen ? 10 : 440},
            right: 0,
        },
        hideLinesFab: {
            position: 'relative',
            zIndex: 1,
            top: 80,
            left: (drawerOpen) => {
                    return drawerOpen ? -10 : 420;
                },
            right: 20,
        }
    }
})

const ExpandFab = styled(Fab)({
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
    top: 2,
    left: 540,
    right: 0,
});

const CollapseFab = styled(Fab)({
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
    top: 10,
    left: 200,
});

export default function Layout({ children }) {
    const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(true);
    const classes = useStyles(drawerOpen);

    return(
            <div>
                <div className={classes.origAppbar}></div>
                <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                    <AppBar elevation={4} ref={widthRef}>
                        <Toolbar className={classes.bar}>
                            {userView ? <div/> : <Tooltip title="Zoom Out (CTR + Wheel)"><Fab className={classes.zoomOutFab} onClick={() => changeZoomCallback(false)} size={'small'}>
                                <Remove sx={{ width: 36, height: 36 }}/>
                            </Fab></Tooltip>}
                            {userView ? <div/> : <Tooltip title="Zoom In (CTR + Wheel)"><Fab className={classes.zoomFab} collapsed={drawerOpen.toString()} onClick={() => changeZoomCallback(true)} size={'small'}>
                                <Add sx={{ width: 36, height: 36 }}/>
                            </Fab></Tooltip>}
                            {userView ? <div/> : <Tooltip title="Hide Page Links"><Fab className={classes.hideLinesFab} collapsed={drawerOpen.toString()} onClick={() => setHideLines(!hideLines)} size={'small'}>
                                <VisibilityOffTwoTone sx={{ width: 36, height: 36 }}/>
                            </Fab></Tooltip>}
                            {userView ? <div/> : <ExpandFab left={drawerOpen ? 10 : 500} onClick={() => setDrawerOpen(true)} size={'small'} sx={drawerOpen ? {display: 'none'} : {}}>
                                <ChevronLeft sx={{ width: 36, height: 36 }}/>
                            </ExpandFab>}
                        </Toolbar>
                    </AppBar>
                    {RIGHT HAND DRAWER ALSO GOES HERE (REMOVED TO SIMPLIFY CODE BASE)}
                </Box>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to this one. The two floating action buttons were rendering into absolute position before everything else had rendered on the first load.
After a page refresh they were rendering into the correct position.

I just had to update from absolute position to relative position to force them to wait for the appbar to render to get them in the right position.

If you have this type of issue which occurs only on the first page load then make sure you haven't set anything with absolute positioning.